# Cold hard truth

Tags: idioms, expressions

I am wondering what does the idiom "cold, hard truth" mean.
Example:

“The atmosphere on Jupiter doesn’t support Netflix,” I said. “That means you won’t be able to watch Peppa Pig.”

> - His face fell, but not for long. He would again start interrogating me to figure out if any of the other planets were less hostile to immigrants. I know it’s a cruel thing to do to a child but **I told him the cold, hard truth** — that he’s trapped on earth for the rest of his life. [Source](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/columns/satire-lessons-from-kindergarten/article37342166.ece/amp/)

Also, please let me know if it is a common idiom especially in AmE?

Comment: I've no idea why, but [apparently,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+cold+truth%2Cthe+hard+truth%2Cthe+cold+hard+truth&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) ***the cold hard truth*** has recently become even more common than just ***the cold truth*** (but the other single-adjective version ***the hard truth*** is much more common than both of those). Personally, I'd be much more likely to use ***the blunt truth***, but the differences between all of these alternatives are trivial, and not worth bothering about. Just use the one you like best.

Comment: It means that the true facts are unpleasant for the person being told them to hear. In this context (telling a young child that they cannot go and live on another planet) it is, of course, used humorously.

Comment: This *may* originate from 'cold, hard cash', but yes, I've been hearing the 'cold, hard' usage a lot more in recent years with anything filling the 'object' place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I trust you know the basic meaning of "truth".

The truth can be hard, when we want to believe something else. It is metaphorically "cold" because it doesn't give us a warm feeling.

So here the child is asking about other planets.  The narrator could lie to the child and say "Sure there are other planets you can go to, and they are more welcoming of immigrants"  This would make the child happy.  But the truth is "You are trapped on Earth".  This is an unpleasant fact, but it is the truth. So it is a cold hard truth.

The particular phrase could be borrowed from the idiom "cold hard cash". Cahs is cold and hard because it is inflexible, but it is also non-negotiable.

It is not very common but there are plenty of examples of its use, and even both a Flim and an unrelated song called "Cold Hard Truth".